# webdriverio - cannot click an element which has a hover effect

Tags: javascript, hover, webdriver-io

Using webdriverio , Im trying to click an a Tag element which has a hover effect when mouse is moved near to that .

i was able to click on this before we introduce hover effect , now the test complains that 
RuntimeError: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (486, 422). Other element would receive the click: ...

Comment: may be a different issue, take a screenshot on a failure and investigate

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you try to click the a tag but doesnt happen with DIV element . at this point of time , as a temporary fix i wanted to use the DIV element at the top of a . But im still wondering  if it is a problem with selenium or webdriverio .

one more thing to consider for this kind of case is 
check that hover effect does not produce another element which covers your link.

Answer (score 0):

This generally happens with chrome. It can not locate the element. So Try something like this by injecting JavaScript snippet:

```
it('hover the element and click on it', function (){
   browser.execute(function(){
   $('selector').trigger("mouseover");
   $('selector').click();
});
});
```

Or is it because the element is not in view port , use:

```
browser.moveToObject(elementSelector);
 // And then after your codes to hover and click
```